# How to align a div bottom of a dynamic div

Tags: jquery

I have a div called content which comes as an ajax content. so how to align a div called footer after the ajax content has loaded using jquery?

Comment: Can you supply some sample html, post the jquery call?

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning. Set the `bottom:` property instead of `top:`

Comment: But onload it is fine, when the page is coming as an ajax call the footer is not moving to the bottom of the page. It remains where in the last height itself. Iam also using swf address to navigation for different pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you parent div be position: relative and the child div be position: absolute. From there, it's pretty simple.

```
.parent
{
    position: relative;
}

.child
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 20px; /*or whatever you want the height to be*/
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The thing is both the div's are positioned absolute, and now we cannot able to change the position for some reason, so is their is a way of doing it when the both div are positon absolute?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u5Az6/ - make the parent element absolute. As you'll see in that link, when you change the parent position, the child position moves with it and stays in the footer position.